# Tramp cannot load larger files (Invalid base64 data)

Tags: tramp

Files above about 5kb fail to load in tramp mode, with the error:

```
tramp-file-name-handler: Invalid base64 data
```

Loading smaller files works fine:

```
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:server:small_file’...
Tramp: Encoding remote file ‘/scp:server:small_file’ with ‘base64 <%s’...done
Tramp: Decoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.13491uQF.py’ with ‘base64-decode-region’...done
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:server:small_file’...done
```

But with larger files I get this:

```
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:server:larger_file’...
Tramp: Encoding remote file ‘/scp:server:larger_file’ with ‘(gzip <%s | base64)’...done
Tramp: Decoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.13491iyp.py’ with ‘(lambda (beg end) (base64-decode-region beg end) (let ((coding-system-for-write (quote binary)) (coding-system-for-read (quote binary)) (default-directory (tramp-compat-temporary-file-directory))) (apply (quote tramp-call-process-region) [scp nil kronos larger_file nil] (point-min) (point-max) (car (split-string gzip -d)) t t nil (cdr (split-string gzip -d)))))’...failed
Tramp: Inserting ‘/scp:server:larger_file’...failed
tramp-file-name-handler: Invalid base64 data
```

I've checked the gzip command on the remote server, it seems to be working. Can I get tramp to keep the intermediate files around so I can inspect them? How else can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Tramp to print traces. Apply `(setq tramp-verbose 6)` prior your test. There will be a Tramp debug buffer, which you shall show, best in the `tramp-devel@gnu.org` mailing list.

If you inspect the debug buffer yourself, follow all trace lines marked with `(6)`. These lines show sent commands, and their output.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Michael! I used that setting to find the transferred string, and I could decode it correctly using gzip and base64 on my local computer. It now appears that this problem only occurs when I open the file using neotree, not with helm. I will ask on tramp-devel.

Comment: @mskel: do you have any updates on this? At the very least, if a fix was not yet done (I'm having the same problem with neotree right now), can you share how you mitigated the problem?

Comment: @MB. : I switched to ranger for filesystem navigation for a while but now I run my editor on the remote host

Comment: Thanks, @mskel: I'm resorting to do the same thing as well. Given how long this bug has been outstanding, I will try and figure out what it is when I get a few spare cycles...