# Tramp open file results in "invalid base64 data"

Tags: tramp

Emacs fails to open some files with Tramp (ssh), I get the error "invalid base64 data", although not always visibly.

I have seen [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/tramp-cannot-load-larger-files-invalid-base64-data), but no solution.

Example with tramp debug (`(setq tramp-verbose 6)`, buffer `*debug tramp/ssh pudu*`) on a file that works:

```
14:23:17.032391 tramp-do-file-attributes-with-perl (5) # file attributes with perl: /Users/gauthier/src/airglow_app/README.md
14:23:17.032481 tramp-send-command (6) # tramp_perl_file_attributes /Users/gauthier/src/airglow_app/README.md integer 2>/dev/null; echo tramp_exit_status $?
14:23:17.056629 tramp-wait-for-regexp (6) # 
(nil 1 502 20 (25137 48410) (25137 48407) (25137 48407) 46.0 33188 t (25 . 49828) -1)
tramp_exit_status 0
///354d40bc54e29ed72bf0c1c6eef9e4a2#$
```

and on a file that fails:

```
14:25:43.478449 tramp-send-command (6) # tramp_perl_file_attributes /Users/gauthier/src/airglow_app/AirGlow_App/AirGlow_App.Android/AirGlow_App.Android.csproj integer 2>/dev/null; echo tramp_exit_status $?
14:25:43.501418 tramp-wait-for-regexp (6) # 
(nil 1 502 20 (25162 53915) (25162 53914) (25162 53914) 19177.0 33188 t (38 . 43118) -1)
tramp_exit_status 0
///354d40bc54e29ed72bf0c1c6eef9e4a2#$
14:25:44.659348 tramp-do-file-attributes-with-perl (5) # file attributes with perl: /Users/gauthier/src/airglow_app/AirGlow_App/AirGlow_App.Android/AirGlow_App.Android.csproj
14:25:44.659644 tramp-send-command (6) # tramp_perl_file_attributes /Users/gauthier/src/airglow_app/AirGlow_App/AirGlow_App.Android/AirGlow_App.Android.csproj integer 2>/dev/null; echo tramp_exit_status $?
14:25:44.681739 tramp-wait-for-regexp (6) # 
(nil 1 502 20 (25162 53915) (25162 53914) (25162 53914) 19177.0 33188 t (38 . 43118) -1)
tramp_exit_status 0
```

This other question seems to say that it is dependent on file size.

What can I do to open all files through Tramp?

---

This works if I start emacs with `-Q`.
Also, `*Messages*` shows this:

```
Tramp: Decoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.5ggoOL.csproj’ with ‘(lambda (beg end) (base64-decode-region beg end) (let ((coding-system-for-write (quote binary)) (coding-system-for-read (quote binary))) (apply (quote tramp-call-process-region) (quote (tramp-file-name ssh nil nil pudu nil /Users/gauthier/src/airglow_app/AirGlow_App/AirGlow_App/AirGlow_App.csproj nil)) (point-min) (point-max) (car (split-string env GZIP= gzip -d)) t t nil (cdr (split-string env GZIP= gzip -d)))))’...failed
```

Comment: Hard to say with the given information. Does it also happen if you start `emacs -Q` only? If yes, pls report a bug via `M-x tramp-bug` and add the traces as explained in the Tramp manual.

Comment: It does not! It's working with -Q. I thought I tested that, so sorry.

Comment: And now... I changed the tramp verbose level to 8, tried to open the file again (no `-Q`) and it worked. Turning back verbose level to 6 and now I can open the file! And unset after a new emacs restart, I can still open the file.